# phpmyadmin run very slow (information_schema)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, information-schema

I have the following scenario with 2 servers (shared hosting):

Linux Server #1 - MySQL 5.5 - 8000 databases

Linux Server #2 - MySQL 5.6 - 7000 databases

By placing phpMyAdmin 4.xx, the first access is very slow on both servers (more than 16 seconds to render the page). Enabling debug, which is unable to identify the queries that it performs the information_schema, as follows:

```
[1f94c8d385c8b4d595d10b6542624c40] => Array (
    [count] => 1
    [query] => SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`SCHEMATA`, (select DB_first_level from ( SELECT distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE AND `SCHEMA_NAME` NOT REGEXP 'information_schema' ) t ORDER BY DB_first_level ASC LIMIT 0, 250) t2 where 1 = locate(concat(DB_first_level, '_'), concat(SCHEMA_NAME, '_')) order by SCHEMA_NAME ASC
    [time] => 3.34156107903
    [trace] => Array (
        [0] => Array(
            [0] => ./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#205: PMA_DatabaseInterface->_dbgQuery()
            [1] => ./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#1705: PMA_DatabaseInterface->tryQuery()
            [2] => ./libraries/navigation/Nodes/Node.class.php#383: PMA_DatabaseInterface->fetchResult()
            [3] => ./libraries/navigation/NavigationTree.class.php#211: Node->getData()
            [4] => ./libraries/navigation/NavigationTree.class.php#674: PMA_NavigationTree->_buildPath()
            [5] => ./libraries/navigation/Navigation.class.php#52: PMA_NavigationTree->renderState()
            [6] => ./libraries/Header.class.php#377: PMA_Navigation->getDisplay()
            [7] => ./libraries/Response.class.php#262: PMA_Header->getDisplay()
            [8] => ./libraries/Response.class.php#275: PMA_Response->_getDisplay()
            [9] => ./libraries/Response.class.php#373: PMA_Response->_htmlResponse()
            [10] => ./libraries/OutputBuffering.class.php#114: PMA_Response::response()
            [11] => PMA_OutputBuffering::stop()
        )
    )
)

[5f54e097676bb853308c7efc720c99f8] => Array (
    [count] => 2
    [query] => select COUNT(*) from ( SELECT distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX(SCHEMA_NAME, '_', 1) DB_first_level FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE TRUE AND `SCHEMA_NAME` NOT REGEXP 'information_schema' ) t 
    [time] => 1.7902340889
    [trace] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [0] => ./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#205: PMA_DatabaseInterface->_dbgQuery()
            [1] => ./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#1563: PMA_DatabaseInterface->tryQuery()
            [2] => ./libraries/navigation/Nodes/Node.class.php#406: PMA_DatabaseInterface->fetchValue()
            [3] => ./libraries/navigation/NavigationTree.class.php#1072: Node->getPresence()
            [4] => ./libraries/navigation/NavigationTree.class.php#677: PMA_NavigationTree->_fastFilterHtml()
            [5] => ./libraries/navigation/Navigation.class.php#52: PMA_NavigationTree->renderState()
            [6] => ./libraries/Header.class.php#377: PMA_Navigation->getDisplay()
            [7] => ./libraries/Response.class.php#262: PMA_Header->getDisplay()
            [8] => ./libraries/Response.class.php#275: PMA_Response->_getDisplay()
            [9] => ./libraries/Response.class.php#373: PMA_Response->_htmlResponse()
            [10] => ./libraries/OutputBuffering.class.php#114: PMA_Response::response()
            [11] => PMA_OutputBuffering::stop()
        )

        [1] => Array (
            [0] => ./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#205: PMA_DatabaseInterface->_dbgQuery()
            [1] => ./libraries/DatabaseInterface.class.php#1563: PMA_DatabaseInterface->tryQuery()
            [2] => ./libraries/navigation/Nodes/Node.class.php#406: PMA_DatabaseInterface->fetchValue()
            [3] => ./libraries/navigation/NavigationTree.class.php#1148: Node->getPresence()
            [4] => ./libraries/navigation/NavigationTree.class.php#678: PMA_NavigationTree->_getPageSelector()
            [5] => ./libraries/navigation/Navigation.class.php#52: PMA_NavigationTree->renderState()
            [6] => ./libraries/Header.class.php#377: PMA_Navigation->getDisplay()
            [7] => ./libraries/Response.class.php#262: PMA_Header->getDisplay()
            [8] => ./libraries/Response.class.php#275: PMA_Response->_getDisplay()
            [9] => ./libraries/Response.class.php#373: PMA_Response->_htmlResponse()
            [10] => ./libraries/OutputBuffering.class.php#114: PMA_Response::response()
            [11] => PMA_OutputBuffering::stop()
        )
    )
)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: I forgot to say, innodb_stats_on_metadata is already OFF.

Answer (score 1):

try setting `innodb_stats_on_metadata` to 0